# JAVA FX - Service.start() wont run in a separate thread

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have and application and i start my scene in the primaryStage.

When the user click OK button, I create a Service and after that, I start it. This service make a call to WebService and get me the response. **I've seen that after the start() is called, the main flow do not continue and createTask() is called immediately** and all my `UI` is blocked. This is my code:

**Code when I press the button**

```
@FXML
    private void handleRegisterButton() {

        User newUser = new User();
        newUser.setUsername(usernameTextField.getText());
        newUser.setGroup(groupChoicheBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        newUser.setMachineName(machineNameTextField.getText());

        RegisterUserInvocation service = new RegisterUserInvocation(newUser);

        service.stateProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
            @Override
            public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
                System.out.println("Task value " + service.getState());
                if(service.getState().equals(Worker.State.SUCCEEDED))
                    System.out.println("SUCCEEDED");
            }
        });

        service.start();

        this.mainApp.getPrimaryStage().close();
    }
```

**Code of RegisterUserInvocation**

```
public class RegisterUserInvocation extends Service<Integer>{
    private User user;

    public RegisterUserInvocation(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<Integer> createTask() {
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/LANServer/services/Rest/user/";
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();      
        Integer resp = client.target(url).request().post(Entity.entity(user, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), Integer.class);

        return new Task<Integer>() {
            @Override
            protected Integer call() throws Exception {
                return resp;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found where i wrong, this is the new code of **RegisterUserInvocation**:

```
public class RegisterUserInvocation extends Service<Integer>{
    private User user;

    public RegisterUserInvocation(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<Integer> createTask() {
        return new Task<Integer>() {
            @Override
            protected Integer call() throws Exception {
                String url = "http://localhost:8080/LANServer/services/Rest/user/";
                Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();      
                Integer resp = client.target(url).request().post(Entity.entity(user, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), Integer.class);

                return resp;
            }
        };
    }
}
```