# JavaFX 8 - Open multiple window from a thread (using afterburnerfx)

Tags: javafx-8

In my application (that run on tray thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323212/java-fx-hide-stage-lost-service-task-response/29324339#29324339) post)i have a thread that with Socket wait for communication.

After received it, i need to open a Window to display the information. Multiple "events" can occur, so i need to update the window with the new event, if it is already opened.

To do this, i cant use the "normal" stage that will be opened when i right click on tray and select some action, because the "events" screen is not dependent from the Tray icon action. Trayicon have the main application (with settings etc), and the Event screen need only for show events.

The problems are:

- How the "infinite" thread that have the Socket, could add the event on the shared observableArrayList() ?
- When the list change, show (if the apposite stage is not already opened) the message or add a new one.

Right now, when i setup the tray icon i do:

```
Platform.runLater(TrayIconManager::createEventStage); // Create the stage for events
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AppGuiceModule()); // I've tried this to share the list, but dont works..
EventsReceiverTask task = new EventsReceiverTask();
injector.injectMembers(task);

 Platform.runLater(task);
```

The stage (in the static TrayIconManager class) is created in this way:

```
private static void createEventStage() {
        eventStage = new Stage();
        NotificationView view = new NotificationView();
        Scene scene = new Scene(view.getView());

        eventStage.setScene(scene);
        // Just create the stage and scene, not show it
    }
```

The NotificationPresenter (with afterburner):

```
@Inject
    EventsDAO eventsDao;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        eventsDao.events().addListener(new ListChangeListener<ScheduledEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends ScheduledEvent> c) {
                System.out.println("Notified me!");
            }

        });

    }
```

And finally the task, where after i receive notification, i'm trying to add to EventsDAO:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            Socket receiver;

            try {

                receiver = serverSocket.accept();
                .......


                eventsDao.addEvent(scheduledEvent); 
                .....
```

Becouse JavaFX need to be executed in own thread, i need to use multiple times Platform.runLater, one times to initialize the stage, and another time to initialize the thread (that use observableArrayList())

Comment: `while(true)` is _bad code_ and will always produce deadlocks - threads cannot be killed reliably (in java), if a thread actively refuses to stop it will run forever --- until you kill the java process itself. Please use something like `while(false == shutdownFlag)`, that'll at least get rid of that beginners' mistake up there.

Comment: Application is current in early stage, this while guard will be removed when i have resolved all other problems. I have many big more problems than this ;)

Comment: many small problems are equal to at least one giant, unsolvable problem. Thats one of the things you need to remember. Its important.

Comment: Sure you are right, the while(true) will be removed.